# About vector orthogonality with itself and implication in a subspace's complement.

Tags: vector-spaces

My definition of vector orthogonality is simply that they are if their dot product is $0$.

I saw a definition that says

> The **orthogonal complement** of a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$is the set of
>   all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are orthogonal to any vector in
>   such subspace.

And I was wondering if the vectors **inside** that subspace would be part of such complement. But that would not be possible because a vector in the subspace would have to test orthogonality with all vectors in the subspace - including itself. But as far as I'm concerned, only the zero vector could fulfil such a thing.

So,

- If a vector is orthogonal with itself, is it the zero vector.
- The orthogonal complement of a subspace will never contain any vector of such subspace - only the zero vector will be.

Are those statements correct?

Comment: yes. you probably know that $||v||^2 = <v,v>$ and $||v|| = 0$ iff $v = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is true in vector spaces over fields of characteristic zero, and the comment from mm-aops is a good way to see it. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29)

In fields of non-zero characteristic, however, a vector may be orthogonal to itself. For example, over $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\}$ (the field with two elements), the vector $(1,1) \in \mathbb{F}_2^2$ is orthogonal to itself since $(1,1) \cdot (1,1) = 1+1 = 0$.